# FFMPEG - Merge 2 Files (video_video), with TC and watermark

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I need to merge two video files, add a watermaker and a timecode burned in the video.

I see this (by @llogan:)

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v:0]drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSansMono.ttf:timecode='01\:23\:45\:00':r=25:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-text_h-20:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxborderw=4:boxcolor=black[bg];[1][bg]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-12:format=auto[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -shortest output.mp4
```

But I can't apply for two videos, because of the map. Can someone help me, please? My last attempt was:

```
ffmpeg -i [video1] -i [video2] -i [image-overlay] -filter_complex "[0:v:0]drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf: timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=25: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=0xccFFFF@1: fontsize=85: box=1: boxcolor=0x000000@0.2[bg];concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv][2:v]overlay=0:0[v];[vv][bg]overlay=0:0" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -b 2000k -preset fast -c:a aac [output file]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to draw timecode to only video1, and concatenate video1 to video2, and add image overlay over the combined videos:

```
ffmpeg -i [video1] -i [video2] -i [image-overlay] -filter_complex "[0:v:0]drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf: timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=25: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=0xccFFFF@1: fontsize=85: box=1: boxcolor=0x000000@0.2[tc];[tc][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[cat][a];[cat][2:v]overlay=0:0[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000k -preset fast -c:a aac [output file]
```